# password_field_tag submits FILTERED value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-development-server

I am new to rails and I am making a simple login page.

this is the code of my view

```
<%= form_tag(:action => 'signup') do %>
    <div class="row">
      <!-- first name -->
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= label_tag('instructor_firstname', 'First Name:') %>
          <%= text_field_tag 'instructor[firstname]', nil, class: 'form-control', required: true %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- first name -->
      <!-- last name -->
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= label_tag('instructor_lastname', 'Last Name:') %>
          <%= text_field_tag 'instructor[lastname]', nil, class: 'form-control', required: true %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- last name -->
    </div>

    <!-- User ID -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= label_tag('instructor_id', 'Instructor ID:') %>
          <%= text_field_tag 'instructor[id]', nil, class: 'form-control', required: true %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- User ID -->

    <!-- password-->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= label_tag('password', 'Password:') %>
          <%= password_field_tag 'password', nil, class: 'form-control', required: true %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- password-->

    <!-- confirm password-->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= label_tag('confirmpassword', 'Confirm Password') %>
          <%= password_field_tag 'confirmpassword', nil, class: 'form-control', required: true %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- confirm password-->

    <!-- error message -->
    <% if !flash[:error].blank? %>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <p><i><small><%= flash[:error] %></small></i></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <!-- error message -->

    <!-- Signup button -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="text-center">
        <%= submit_tag 'Sign up', class: 'btn btn-default' %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Signup button -->
<% end %>
```

but when I check the parameters submitted the result is

```
"instructor"=>{"firstname"=>"Gerald", "lastname"=>"Campana", "id"=>"2112"}, "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "confirmpassword"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Sign up"}
```

I can't compare the two password, even if I tried to display it to the console using puts params[:instructor][:password] it shows nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
password_field_tag 'instructor[password]', nil, class: 'form-control', required: true 
password_field_tag 'instructor[confirmpassword]', nil, class: 'form-control', required: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you not to develop your own authentication system, but to use a simple yet very advanced gem for that - device

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

It will save you a lot of headaches, allow you a lot of authentication related features and will make sure you don't have any vulnerabilities in your code.